# How to signin with ReactJS, NodeJS using MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am a beginner developer on ReactJS, I want to signin my form using ReactJS, NodeJS and MySQL.

My class Login is below :

```
     handleClick(event){
    var self = this;
    var payload={
      "username":this.state.username,
        "password":this.state.password
    }
    axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/app/login/',
          data: payload,
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
          }
        })

   .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
     if(response.data.code == 200){

    this.props.history.push("http://localhost:5000/brillo#/");
     }
     else{
       swal("Erreur !", "Erreur !", "error");
     }
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
   });
  }
  handleredirect(){
    this.props.history.push("/register");
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">

                    <Form  method="POST" >

                      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                        <Input type="text" placeholder="Username" autoComplete="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })} required/>
                      </InputGroup>
                      <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                        <Input type="password" value={this.state.password} placeholder="Password" onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value })} autoComplete="current-password"   required/>
                      </InputGroup>
                      <Row>
                        <Col xs="6">
                          <Button type="button" color="primary" className="px-4" onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}>Login</Button>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
                          <Button color="link" className="px-0">Forgot password?</Button>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Form>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

My router :

```
exports.login = function(req,res){
  var email= req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
 var username = req.params.username;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?',[username], function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {
   res.send({
      "code":400,
      "failed":"error ocurred"
    })
  }else{
    if(results.length >0){
      bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, function(err, doesMatch){
        if (doesMatch){
     res.send({
       "code":200,
       "success":"login sucessfull"
         });
      }else{
     res.send({
       "code":204,
       "success":"Email and password does not match"
         });
      }
    });
  }
    else{
      res.send({
        "code":204,
        "success":"Email does not exits"
          });
    }
  }
  });

}
```

When I run my backend with Postman  by posting `http://localhost:4000/app/login/` I get :

```
{
    "code": 204,
    "success": "Email does not exits"
}
```

But I post with the username and the password that I submitted on the register form and when I run my frontend, I get :

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config:
{
data:
code:204
success:"Email does not exits"
```

I want when I click on the login button, it will be redirected to the dashboard page.

How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

your nodejs router seems not correct, you take from body email ,password ,username but the email is not send by react. Then what you're looking for in your Database, email or username ?

Next in line

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?',[username], function...
```

I think it should be more like :

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = \'' + username + '\'', function...
```

And by the way, you response is not correct : you should return :

```
return res.status(500).json({ failed: 'error ocurred'})
```

and not

```
res.send({"code":400,"failed":"error ocurred"})
```

Comment: when I change it, I get : `{
    "failed": "error ocurred"
}`

Comment: print the error in the failed json response to help you. 

return res.status(500).json({ failed: 'error ocurred: ' + error})

And also for each res.send you should transform to the correct res.status(XXX).json(JSON.OBJ) and add a return before (But this is not your current problem)

Comment: I get : `xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:5000/app/login/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:51
Login.js:51 Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)`